# Find a measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}(g(\mathcal{N}(0,1)))=2$

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, measurable-functions

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ a random variable. Find a measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}(g(X))=2$.

Comment: Hint: What is E(X^2)? Simpler: What is E(X)? Even simpler: What is E(1)?

Answer (score -1):

We know that the density function of $X$ is

$f_X(s)={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-s^2\over 2}$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a function defined by
$$
\\ g(s)=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{s^2\over 2}\cdot\textbf{1}_{\{0\leq s\leq 2\}}\ \
$$
$s\mapsto \textbf{1}_{\{0\leq s \leq 2\} }$ is a measurable function because it's a linear combination of indicators of borel sets, $s\mapsto\sqrt{2\pi}e^{s^2\over 2}$ is a measurable function because it's continuous, and $g$ is a measurable function because it's a composition of measurable functions. Thus,
$$
\\ \mathbb{E}(g(X))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(s)f_X(s)ds=\int_0^2ds=2  \ 
$$

Comment: This is fine and dandy but far too complicated, maybe?  What if $g(x) = x+2$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$? Is $g(x)$ measurable? What is $E[g(X)] = E[X+2]$?